# What is a traceable pointer in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

Trying to understand clause 20 in ISO Standard c++:

> Change: Minimal support for garbage-collected regions.
>
> Rationale: Required by new feature.
>
> Effect on original feature: Valid C++ 2003 code, compiled without traceable pointer support, that interacts with newer C++ code using regions declared reachable may have different runtime behavior.

https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4618/diff.cpp03.utilities

What is a traceable pointer (not  a traceable pointer object)? What is the difference between a traceable pointer and a normal pointer?

Comment: _traceable pointer object_ is defined in https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4618/basic.stc.dynamic.safety FYI but it would be great if someone explained all the interesting bits - i.e., what it's for, who has strict pointer safety and who doesn't, etc etc

Answer (score 8):

There doesn't seem to be a definition of the term *traceable pointer* in the C++ standard. That is, it is almost certainly referring to a *traceable pointer object*. You can raise a defect to get things corrected, i.e., either have the wording amended to define *traceable pointer* or to refer to *traceable pointer object*. As Annex C doesn't have mandatory impact on the standard, I'd guess it would get editorially fixed. The garbage collection support is also a section which isn't super popular as people like to play tricks with pointers and, e.g., use unused bits to store information.

Semantically, traceable object pointers is what is needed for the minimal garbage collection support. The key idea is that pointer values can't be "hidden", i.e., have their bit pattern modified, and can be identified by a garbage collect and objects which aren't referenced that way may get collected. The definitions constrain, e.g., the portability of the doubly linked list implementation using one pointer to store the XORed pointers to the previous and next node whose traversal depends on knowing the node you are coming from and the current node to move to the next node: the XORed value is not a *safely-derived pointer*. Likewise, I think setting bits which are known to be zero due to alignment constraints or because only some of the bits in a pointer are used for addresses (e.g., 48 bits out of the 64 bit pointer value) wouldn't necessarily be portable.

The functions in section 20 are used to declare additional "root" objects so the garbage collector doesn't reuse memory of objects which are somehow considered to be alive although the C++ implementation itself doesn't know how to arrive at them. For example, you could declare pointers to be reachable before storing their values into a file which is then later read again to recover their location.

Of course, C++ doesn't have mandatory garbage collection. There exist custom garbage collectors for C++, though. Even in programs written to not require a garbage collector a garbage collector could be interesting to locate memory leaks.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin: the section [basic.stc.dynamic.safety] in the standard does include `std::uintptr_t`. My description tries to capture the intent, leaving the legalese to the standard. The pointers can be the result of `new` expressions, taking the address of objects, pointer arithmetic, or certain casts. The fact that integers can be confused by integers is will known but garbage collectors don't necessarily care about the odd integer (or `double`) looking like a pointer: in the worst case an object is kept alive which could have been released but otherwise there is no harm done.

Comment: @davidbak provided the definition I looked for.